# How to do multiple Ajax calls when page is first loaded while using the same HTML divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have my HTML site set up where I pass a div id as data into my Ajax.

```
<div id="1" class="stats">
    DATA GOES IN HERE
</div>
<div id="2" class="stats">
    DATA GOES IN HERE
</div>
```

I have it so that when the page first loads, an Ajax call is loaded that finds the div id and makes use of it back-end to bring the DATA forward.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var fId = $(".stats").attr("id");
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_stats',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {fId : fId},
    success: function(data) {
        $("#"+fId).html(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("ERROR: " + data);
    }
});
});
```

The data can be brought. However, I have about 26 of these divs and I need to do this call 26 times. The problem is, the call is only made once and the data is only loaded for the very first div.

How can I make it so that I pass the data from all 26 divs into the Ajax call and bring it into the HTML when the page is first loaded?

Comment: How should the data in all the `div`s be organized? One big string? Any delimiters? An array?

Comment: Don't make 26 AJAX requests as the page loads. Get all the data server side and send it to the client without making any unnecessary AJAX requests at all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The data in the divs are just String values

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Would a normal Javascript call be fine too?

Comment: No. The problem is making that number of AJAX requests, not which library you use to make them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".stats").each((i,e)=>{
     let fId=$(e).attr("id");
     $.ajax({
       url: 'get_stats',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {fId : fId},
       success: function(data) {
         $("#"+fId).html(data);
       },
       error: function(data){
         alert("ERROR: " + data);
       }
     });   
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="stats">
    DATA GOES IN HERE
</div>
<div id="2" class="stats">
    DATA GOES IN HERE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that with a loop like:

```
let divs = $(".stats");

$.each(divs, function (div) {
     //..do your ajax request here
});
```

Comment: You *can*, but you really *shouldn't*